# Convert string to enum without a value swift

Tags: swift, enums

I'm making a permissions system, and the emum below shows the possible permissions for an advance. I get the permissions from the server as a string: `advance.answer.view`. Is there any way to convert that string into the enum `Advance.Answer.View`?

```
enum Advance {

        case View, Edit

        enum Answer { case View, Edit }
        enum Ride { case View, Edit }
        enum Contact { case View, Edit }
        enum Document { case View, Edit }
        enum Guest { case View, Edit }
        enum Section { case View, Edit, Create }
        enum Member { case View, Edit }
        enum Flight { case View, Edit }
        enum Location { case View, Edit }
        enum Time { case View, Edit }
        enum Event { case View, Edit }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the enum a String rawvalue like

```
enum Answer:String {
  case View = "View"
  case Edit = "Edit"
  init(s:String) {
    if s == "xy" { self = .View}
    else { self = .Edit }
  }
  mutating func fromString(s:String) {
    if s == "xy" { self = .View}
  }
}

var answer1 = Answer(rawValue:"View")!
var answer2 = Answer(s:"x")
answer2.fromString("xy")
```

Comment: Is there any way around this? I have so many values and it seems redudant.

Comment: You can write a `fromString` function.

Comment: How would that work? Could u post some code? I can't think of how such a function would work in an efficient way.

Comment: See my changes in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your visual structure into:

```
enum Advance {
    case Answer(view: Bool, edit: Bool)
}

// usage
Advance.Answer(view: false, edit: true)
```

UPD.
Another case:

```
enum Advance: String {
    case View = "view", Edit = "edit"

    static func getEnumType(value: String) -> EnumProtocol.Type {
        switch value {
            case "contact":
                return Contact.self

            default:
                return Answer.self
        }
    }

    enum Answer: String, EnumProtocol {
        init(rawValue: String) {
            switch rawValue {
                case "edit":
                    self = .Edit

                default:
                    self = .View
            }
        }

        case View = "view", Edit = "edit"
    }

    enum Contact: String, EnumProtocol {
        init(rawValue: String) {
            switch rawValue {
                case "write":
                    self = .Write

                case "edit":
                    self = .Edit

                default:
                    self = .View
            }
        }

        case View = "view", Edit = "edit", Write = "write"
    }
}
```

EnumProtocol you can extend with get function of rawValue.

```
protocol EnumProtocol {
    init(rawValue: String)
}
```

**Update at (31/01/2016)**

Usage:

```
Advance.getEnumType("contact").init(rawValue: "write") // Advance.Contact.Write
Advance.getEnumType("unknown").init(rawValue: "abc") // Advance.Answer.View
```

Comment: how could I then check the values true or false

Comment: enum Advance {
    case Time(view: Bool, edit: Bool)
}

let someEnum: Advance = .Time(view: true, edit: false)
switch someEnum {
    case .Time(let a, let b):
        println("Time. view: \(a) edit: \(b)")
    
    default: break
}

Comment: how would i check if I can view the time in an if statement though @dimpiax

Comment: Through "if statement" can't.